# Doctrine trying to persist Owner

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-forms

I've setup Doctrine and Symfony-forms independent of the Symfony Framework (as I don't need most of it).

The issue I'm having is, when trying to persist a new "Audit" which has an "Type" doctrine seems to want to persist the owning side of the relationship (Type).

For example as Audit may have a type of  Vehicle Service.

```
 // -- Model/Audit.php --
 /**
 * @var \Model\Type
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Model\Audit\Type", inversedBy="audits")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
private $type;
/**
 * Set type
 *
 * @param \Model\Type $type
 * @return Audit
 */
public function setType(\Model\Type $type)
{
    $this->type = $type;
    return $this;
}
```

And then in the inverse side:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Model\Audit", mappedBy="type")
 * @var type */
private $audits;

public function __construct() {
     $this->audits = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Persistance code looks as follows:

```
$data = $form->getData();
$entityManager->persist($data);
$entityManager->flush();
```

And finally the form class is:

```
class AuditType extends AbstractType {

   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
       $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('type', 'entity', array(
                'class' => "Model\Type"
            ));
  }
```

All looks (to me at least) exactly the same as in all the documentations both Doctrine and Symfony sides but I'm getting this error:

> A new entity was found through the relationship 'Model\Audit#type'
>   that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity:
>   Vehicle Service. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call
>   EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade
>   persist this association in the mapping for example
>   @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"})."

Which is really frustrating as I don't want to persist the Type side, I just want to put (in most basic terms) the id of 3 into the type_id column. Yet Doctrine seems to think I want to create a new "Type" which I certainly do not. They already exist.

---

Using $entityManager->merge($audit); works in part, it allows the inital Audit and its FK's to be saved. However it caused any embedded forms to become ignored.

Comment: In your form builder, try changing the 'type' entry to **->add('type', EntityType::class, array(**

Comment: Entity as is, is the same as EntityType:: but for older versions of PHP I didn't mention but I'm limited to 5.3 so therefore symfony-form 2.6..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need set

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Model\Audit", mappedBy="type")
 * @var type
 */
 private $audits;

 public function __construct() {
 $this->audits = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
 }

/**
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getAudits()
{
    return $this->audits;
}

/**
 * @param Audit $audit
 */
public function addAudits(Audit $audit)
{
    $this->audits->add($audit);
    $audit->setTyoe($this);
}
```

and in Type Audit.model

```
     // -- Model/Audit.php --
   /**
   * @var \Model\Type
   *
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Model\Audit\Type", inversedBy="audits")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
   */
   private $type;
   /**
   * Set type
   *
   * @param \Model\Type $type
   * @return Audit
   */
   public function setType(\Model\Type $type)
   {
      $this->type = $type;
   }
```